# CMMotionManager and the SceneKit Coordinate System

Tags: objective-c, scenekit

I'm trying to build a rolling marble type game. I've decided to convert from Cocos3D to SceneKit so I have probably primitive questions about code snippets.

Here is my CMMotionManager setup. Problem is that as I change my device orientation, the gravity direction also changes (not properly adjusting to device orientation). This code only works with Landscape Left orientation.

```
-(void) setupMotionManager
{ 
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue    withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error)
{
CMAcceleration acceleration = [accelerometerData acceleration];

float accelX = 9.8 * acceleration.y;
float accelY = -9.8 * acceleration.x;
float accelZ = 9.8 * acceleration.z;

scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(accelX, accelY, accelZ);
}];

}
```

This code came from a marble demo from apple. I translated it from Swift to Obj-C.

If I want it to work in Landscape Right I need to change last line to

```
scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(-accelX, -accelY, accelZ);
```

This brings up another question... If Y is Up in SceneKit, why is it the accelZ variable that needs no change? So my question is how does CMMotionManager coordinates relate to Scene coordinates?

Comment: The solution to figuring out how CMMotionManager works is to NSLog the CMAcceleration data and figure it out :) When no one can help go back to the basics... log, log log :)